# useEffect running infinite loop, although it supposed to work once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have this effect which supposed to work once, but it is going infinite loop. can we get an explanation of what's happening?

```js
   useEffect(() => {
     (async () => {
       const cartId = localStorage.getItem('cart-id');
       try {
         const {cart, products} = await (await fetch('/api/cart' + (cartId ? '?id=' + cartId : ''))).json();
         setCart(cart);
         setProducts(products);
       } catch (e) {}
     })();
   }, []);
```

I have the cart-id successfully.

try-catch supposed to work once, even if I don't get any products for any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd parameter (empty array in your example) allows to run your code, only if the params changed. to make use of that try make your effect dependant on cartId

```
  const cartId = localStorage.getItem('cart-id');
  useEffect(() => (async () => {
       try {
         const {cart, products} = await (await fetch('/api/cart' + (cartId ? '?id=' + cartId : ''))).json();
         setCart(cart);
         setProducts(products);
       } catch (e) {}
     })(), [cartId]);
```

Comment: I guess putting async, at the top level of useEffect, might cause rendering twice, first when promise fired, then when its fulfilled or rejected.

Comment: that's why I always wrap async inside useEffect with this anonymous call

Comment: you are right, the type is incompatible. use wrapper then. I returned back the callback inside of an answer